# SQL Server : non-clustered index is not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, non-clustered-index

I have a table with a few columns along including a primary key. I have created this non-clustered index on the table:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [nci_wi_plan_239F85C77AF7B2990845ACFEE404C263] 
ON dbo.[Plans] ([template_id] ASC, [deleted] ASC)
INCLUDE([HasWorkouts]) WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

I am executing this query in a stored procedure to get result from table:

```
select 
     dp.id
    ,dp.HasWorkouts
from dbo.Plans dp
where dp.template_id= @TemplateId and dp.deleted = 0 
--((@TemplateId = 0 or @TemplateId is null) or (dp.template_id= @TemplateId)) // not working if I use this line
```

In above query, non-clustered index is only works if I directed check `template_id` with some id. But some time I may not required to check `dp.template_id` so I set `0 or null` to `@TemplateId` while executing procedure. Is there any way to **check  or skip** `template_id` along with non-clustered index?

Edit:-

Check below screenshot. if I `dp.template_id= @TemplateId and dp.deleted = 0` in where clause

[image]

ANd if I use `((@TemplateId = 0 or @TemplateId is null) or (dp.template_id= @TemplateId)) and dp.deleted = 0`

[image]

Comment: So your question is why your query does not use this index. You have sufficient rep and experience to post a question that better reflects your issue. Erland discusses [dynamic search conditions](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html) in great detail - including the use of the recompile option

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the @TemplateId as foreign key? and drop the template_id? I mean why would you need to verify a variable against two values when you can check it against one?

Comment: `template_id` is column from table. And `@TemplateId` is a variable which I used to pass value to stored procedure. `template_id` is already foreign key.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-index-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15 

I suggest checking this link

Answer (score 0):

Add the `OPTION(RECOMPLE)` query hint. SQL Server can then use [constant folding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/query-processing-architecture-guide?view=sql-server-ver15) to evaluate the values during compilation and eliminate the unneeded predicates from the plan.

The downside with `OPTION(RECOMPLE)` is the plan will not be reused, which might be a concern if the query is executed at high frequency (i.e. many times per second). In that case, instead of a single query, you could use an `IF` construct to execute different queries depending on the values. That will cache both plans.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to check template_id simply don`t do it:

```
IF @template_id IS NULL OR @template_id = 0
   SELECT p.id dp.HasWorkouts
   FROM dbo.Plans dp
   WHERE dp.deleted = 0 
ELSE 
   SELECT dp.id ,dp.HasWorkouts
   FROM dbo.Plans dp
   WHERE dp.template_id= @TemplateId and dp.deleted = 0
```

These are really two queries and the best covering indexes are;

```
CREATE INDEX ix_template_id_is_deleted ON dbo.Plans(template_id, is_deleted)
INCLUDE (id, HasWorkouts)
```

AND

```
CREATE INDEX ix_plans_is_deleted ON dbo.Plans(is_deleted)
INCLUDE (id, hasWorkouts)
```

The other way to it is by an unique query like this:

```
SELECT dp.id, dp.HasWorkouts
FROM dbo.Plans dp
WHERE
   (@template_id = 0 OR @template_id IS NULL OR dp.template_id= @TemplateId) 
   and dp.deleted = 0 
OPTION (RECOMPILE)
```

But this require recompiling the query evey time it executes to be efficent.

Another index that might worth trying is the following:

```
CREATE INDEX ix_template_not_deleted ON dbo.Plans(template_id)
INCLUDE (id, HasWorkouts)
WHERE is_deleted = 0
```

I think  testing this index is worth because I think this index is enough for both queries and is its smaller.